# Download WorkflowOutboundMessage type from metadata API

Tags: workflow, metadata, metadata-api, workflowoutboundmessage

Attempting to perform a deploy on a set of unpackaged `Workflow Rules` and I'm getting an error that my workflows are missing: `WorkflowOutboundMessage` - *is it possible to download these in the IDE or via the metadata api*?

I'm not seeing the type listed in the available 'Metadata Types' in the IDE?

I do see a folder called 'Flows' but it doesn't list anything...

Comment: I think my issue was the `User` didn't exist in the target org! After I correct this they uploaded correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Workflow rules and actions are contained in a single metadata file per object with the format like so: `workflows/Custom_Object__c.workflow` This is accessible by retrieving the "Workflows" through the IDE (but also through the metadata api)

One more spanner in the works is that if the Workflow rules/actions are for a managed object they will not be in the same location. They will be in the folder in the IDE `Referenced Packages/[Package Name]/workflows/Custom_Object__c.workflow`. I don't know what the implications in the metadata api are for managed objects as I haven't tried

[image: IDE Workflows]

Answer (score 0):

Outbound messages are just one of the configurable actions for a workflow rules (others being field update, task, email). They can be found in the `.workflow` metadata file, which is possible to pull down into the IDE.

```
<outboundMessages>
        <fullName>Account_Outbound</fullName>
        <apiVersion>8.0</apiVersion>
        <endpointUrl>https://.....</endpointUrl>
        <fields>Id</fields>
        <fields>Name</fields>
```

To pull down Workflows, select Workflow from Project Properties > Force.com > Project Contents > Add/Remove (in the IDE)